# Why is my Bootstrap code not working?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

Tonight I decided to give Bootstrap a try (only been doing CSS/HTML for about two weeks), but I'm running into a problem. For whatever reason, it doesn't seem like my HTML doc is linking to the Bootstrap stylesheet. I used one of their dropdown code snippets, but the end result isn't stylized. Can someone see if I'm doing something wrong? Below is my HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html lang = "en">

<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
<li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
<li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
<li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
<li class="divider"></li>
<li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wonder if you need both `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css` included. Usually the former is an unminified version of the latter, and you only need one or the other included.

Comment: @JaredFarrish True, but that doesn't fix the problem. I'm new to this stuff so it's probably a n00by problem.

Comment: I didn't think it would either (hence the comment and not an answer). Just a heads-up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are all the files in the right folders? You are using relative url:s, can be confusing if you just started to code. How is your folder structure? Are the index.html and the css folder in the same directory?

Answer (score 2):

You Need to look at the file structure of how bootstrap files are added:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html#file-structure

Comment: this site it not working now and giving 404 error by saying
There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.

Answer (score 0):

try add "style="display: block; position: static; margin-bottom: 5px; *width: 180px"

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" style="display: block; position: static; margin-bottom: 5px; *width: 180px;">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
```